# how to resolve error "lambda role already exists" while execution of lambda function using serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, serverless-framework

my yml file look like this

```
org: saadakramdsg
app: timesss
service: Timezone
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

I am unable to understand the cause of this error.I have searched this on internet but I can't find anything useful about this.Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately not enough data to narrow down the root cause. I would start by deleting the IAM role related to Lambda service here:
[+] https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home?region=us-east-1#/roles

If that doesn't work,

- check what lambda role is your configuration trying to create.
- see if your stack can reference an already existing Lambda role

Hope it helps